# Can Istio use existing zipkin?

Tags: zipkin, istio

Can istio send tracing information to an external zipkin instance? It seems like istio has hard coded zipkin address several places to expect it in the istio-system namespace(by referencing it without a namespace).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to as long as you use the fully qualified domain name. For instance, `zipkin.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local`.